# Запись в поле таблицы нескольких значений за один цикл

Tags: php

Есть поле для загрузки файлов: <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="img[]" />

Есть цикл for:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['img']['name']); $i++)
{

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['img']['name'][$i]);
}
```

В таблице есть поле img

Допустим, чел выбрал 5 фоток и загрузил их

ВНИМАНИЕ! ВОПРОС!
    как мне записать имена этих фоток в поле img, чтобы не переписывалось значение? и разделять их символов |

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['img']['name']); $i++) {
    $images[] = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['img']['name'][$i]);
}

query("UPDATE tab1 SET img = CONCAT(IFNULL(img, ''),'|" . implode('|',$images) . "') WHERE ...");
```